# Fastest way to test if a list has items or not

Tags: 2013

How can I quickly find out if a list has items in it or not?

Using SharePoint C#

I like to try anything possible but it has to be fast

Comment: what programming model are you planning to use - Server, CSOM, and/or App REST ?

Answer (score 1):

`list.Items.Count` if it does has folders or deleted items. This does it through a query.

If you are not worried on deleted/checked out items or folders, go with `list.ItemCount`

Comment: assign the output to an int type variable. Then check whether it is greater than 0. Before that also make sure the list object also not null.

Comment: What do you mean by how? Don't you know how to use C# code inside SharePoint? Please explain your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Manager http://spm.codeplex.com/

You can't really get more complete than that.

Comment: He has mentioned it should be using C#

Comment: SharePoint Manager uses the SharePoint serverside object model